# Data Factory Set variable with KeyVault Value

Tags: azure-data-factory

How can I set a variable with the value that I have stored in a KeyVault secret?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**
Hi @willy sepulveda. We only can secure the input and output in Web Activity,like follows:
[image]
Input and output data will be sensitive:
[image]

---

You can use Web activity to access the Key Valut value. Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities). I also created a test.

1. Open the properties of your data factory and copy the **Managed Identity Object ID** value. Open the key vault access policies and add the managed identity permissions to Get and List secrets.
   [image]
2. Then I created a secret named `myKey` and set the value `helloworld`.

**Note:** The name of the secret (`myKey`) will be used below at Step 5.
[image]

3. Declare a String type variable named `myVar` in ADF pipeline.
   [image]
4. In `Web1` activity, select **Sceure output**.
   [image]
5. `Web1` activity settings
   **URL:**  `https://<your-keyvalut-name>.vault.azure.net/secrets/<your-secret-name>?api-version=7.0`.

> You need replace keyvalut name and secret name.

**Authentication:** Select `Managed Identity`.
**Resource:** Enter `https://vault.azure.net`.
[image]

6. In `Set variable1` activity, add dynamic content `@activity('Web1').output.value`.
   [image]
7. Debug result: I can see that the variable successfully received the secret value.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I tried it and it worked perfectly .. one final question: what can I do to not depend on the version of the api because if this version changes I could have problems or I'm wrong

Comment: Hi@willy sepulveda. According to this [api manua]l(https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/keyvault/getkey) and [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities) , for us as users, we can only use the officially designated version. Sorry, I didn't get any other useful information from the official website.

Comment: Hi@Joseph Xu, Thank you so much for your great answer, if I have to send the value of the secret to a variable, how can I configure this variable with secure input and output? is this possible???

Comment: Hi@willy sepulveda. We only can secure the input and output in Web Activity, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi@Joseph Xu, Thank you again, this option to ensure the input and output in the web activity is great, I only have a doubt is: if the value of the secret is encrypted at the output of the web activity but when another activity receives it inside the pipeline is it not entered as encrypted? Unless the input of the new activity is configured as safe, am I correct?